# Dynamic Data Associate Related Table Value?

Tags: linq, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have create a LINQ-to-SQL project in Visual Studio 2010 using Dynamic Data. In this project I have two tables. One is called phones_extension and the other phones_ten. The list of columns in phones_extension looks like this:
id, extension, prefix, did_flag, len, ten_id, restriction_class_id, sfc_id, name_display, building_id, floor, room, phone_id, department_id
In phones_ten it looks like this:
id, name, pbxid
Now, I'd like to be able to somehow make it so that there is an association (or inheritance?) that essentially results in me being able to make a query like phones_extension.ten and it gives me the result of phones_ten.name. Right now I have to get phones_extension.ten_id and then match that against phones_ten.id - I'm trying to get the DBML to handle this translation automatically.
Is this possible?

Comment: AH! Wall of words!  (you should use the "code" button to format things like your lists of columns or even bullets. The unformatted list makes it more difficult to separate the the meat from the mush. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Dave, you need to setup a relatioship in the DB for this to work in Linq to SQL you could just create the relatioship (association in L2S) but there will need to be a primary key on each table anyway to allows edits.